# C# IConnectionPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint throws exception

Tags: c#, callback, com, atl

I am trying to implement an ATL COM module with a connection point. The source code for this is all pretty much boilerplate that I copied by example from chapter 12 of *Developer's Workshop to COM and ATL 3.0* by Andrew W. Troelsen.

That's a lot of code, with three source files (almost all Visual Studio rendered boilerplate).

I think have got everything that I need, though. There is a subclass called _IFooEvents_CP.h to handle events and the class implemments IConnectionPointImpl:
using namespace ATL;

```
template <class T>
class CProxy_IFooEvents : public IConnectionPointImpl<T, &__uuidof( _IFooEvents ), CComDynamicUnkArray>
{
    // WARNING: This class may be regenerated by the wizard
public:
        HRESULT Fire()
     {
     //...
     // event proxy code
     //...
     }

}
```

Then, in the header to my coclass (Foo, of course):

```
// Foo.h : Declaration of the CFoo

#pragma once
#include "resource.h"       // main symbols



#include "ConnectionPointTest_i.h"
#include "_IFooEvents_CP.h"



#if defined(_WIN32_WCE) && !defined(_CE_DCOM) && !defined(_CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA)
#error "Single-threaded COM objects are not properly supported on Windows CE platform, such as the Windows Mobile platforms that do not include full DCOM support. Define _CE_ALLOW_SINGLE_THREADED_OBJECTS_IN_MTA to force ATL to support creating single-thread COM object's and allow use of it's single-threaded COM object implementations. The threading model in your rgs file was set to 'Free' as that is the only threading model supported in non DCOM Windows CE platforms."
#endif

using namespace ATL;


// CFoo

class ATL_NO_VTABLE CFoo :
    public CComObjectRootEx<CComSingleThreadModel>,
    public CComCoClass<CFoo, &CLSID_Foo>,
    public IConnectionPointContainerImpl<CFoo>,
    public IDispatchImpl<IFoo, &IID_IFoo, &LIBID_ConnectionPointTestLib, /*wMajor =*/ 1, /*wMinor =*/ 0>,
    public CProxy_IFooEvents<CFoo>
{
public:
    CFoo()
    {
    }

DECLARE_REGISTRY_RESOURCEID(IDR_FOO)


BEGIN_COM_MAP(CFoo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IFoo)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IDispatch)
    COM_INTERFACE_ENTRY(IConnectionPointContainer)
END_COM_MAP()

BEGIN_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP(CFoo)
    CONNECTION_POINT_ENTRY(__uuidof(_IFooEvents))
END_CONNECTION_POINT_MAP()
```

Furthermore, the idl file has the event source forward declared and all set thanks to the ATL connection point wizard that I used to make this thing:

```
library ConnectionPointTestLib
{
    importlib("stdole2.tlb");
    [
        uuid(25EAB56B-884A-4AA9-B470-BAA975E08343)      
    ]
    dispinterface _IFooEvents
    {
        properties:
        methods:
            [id(1), helpstring("test")] HRESULT bar();
    };
    [
        uuid(54B6050F-1090-4660-9DF0-D8A0853F96CF)      
    ]
    coclass Foo
    {
        [default] interface IFoo;
        [default, source] dispinterface _IFooEvents;
    };
};
```

So, I have an implementation of the connection point container interface, I have a connection point in the connection point map, and I have forward declared an event function to implement on the client side.

It compiles without warning or error. Then on the C# side I have the following:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.IO;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComTypes;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using ConnectionPointTestLib;

namespace TestConnectionPoint
{
    class EventSink
    {
        public EventSink() { }
        public void bar()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("hello");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

                ConnectionPointTestLib.IFoo cpTest = new ConnectionPointTestLib.Foo();

                IConnectionPointContainer icpc;
                icpc = (IConnectionPointContainer)cpTest;
                IConnectionPoint icp;
                Guid id = typeof(Foo).GUID;

                icpc.FindConnectionPoint(ref id, out icp);


                EventSink es = new EventSink();
                int cookie;
                icp.Advise(es, out cookie);

                cpTest.testCP();
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
            catch (COMException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The exception is thrown on this line:

```
 icpc.FindConnectionPoint(ref id, out icp);
```

and the error code is exotic: 0x80040200. I couldn't locate this code anywhere, but I think it is not an official Windows code. At least, I couldn't find it on MSDN's list.

I copied the client code from an example I found online, so it could be that I am missing a step.

Later:
As @Hans Passant pointed out, the error code is CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION. My understanding is that this means that there are no connections exposed by the interface. But, as far as I can tell (and I am new to this game) I have done everything I need to do in order to have an outgoinginterface here.

I feel like I'm missing some tiny magical step.

Comment: It is the value of CONNECT_E_NOCONNECTION, one of the documented error codes for FindConnectionPoint().  Makes it pretty official.  Not so sure why they made it difficult to find back, but you can locate it in the OleCtl.h SDK header file.

Comment: @HansPassant: Thanks for the clarification. So it appears that it is my COM component afterall. Not sure why this would happen, unfortunately, or how to post the code for something so intricate on stackoverflow!

Comment: Looks like you simply using the wrong GUID.  Not Foo, it has to be the Guid of the interface, _IFooEvents

Comment: Yes! That is exactly right. I now get past the FindConnectionPoint step. Though, I still get an error on Advise. I will start a new post if that continues to be an issue. It's a different question.